# Enable TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 in Docker image without OpenSSL

Tags: docker, ssl, asp.net-web-api, tls1.2

So I'm a little new to Docker, and I'm trying to host a .NET 6.0 API inside of a Docker Image and Container on a remote server for testing. The problem is that the API is trying to communicate with a legacy 2008 SQL server that's not using TLS 1.2, so when the API attempts to communicate with the server inside the Docker Container, a pre-login handshake failure occurs. However, when running by itself, the API is able to communicate with the SQL server fine.

I've seen some approaches where people suggest putting the following in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN sed -i 's/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=2/DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

However, since I'll be running this on a remote server that doesn't have OpenSSL downloaded, this isn't an option. Is there a way that a specific Docker Image can be configured and forced to use TLS 1.0 for testing?

Comment: Did you try to add TrustServerCertificate=True to the connexionstring?